# Possible bug with graphicx

Tags: graphics

I have a small file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{fig}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

accompanied of a figure in PDF, that when processed by pdflatex and lualatex produces a fine PDF, but when processed by "xelatex" the figure is rendered upside down. The figure is at:

```
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv8plo9k58s8cnl/fig.pdf
```

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Comment: It's not `graphicx` or indeed LaTeX at all: one sees the same with a plain TeX test file such as`\XeTeXpdffile fig.pdf\bye`: I suspect the PDF itself is at fault.

Comment: @JosephWright The PDF is produced with xelatex.

Comment: Not according to the PDF properties!: `/Creator (pdftk 2.02 - www.pdftk.com)`
`/Producer (itext-paulo-155 \(itextpdf.sf.net-lowagie.com\))`

Comment: And it contains a `/Rotate 180`.

Comment: You are correct, it has been produced by XeTeX and then rotated, cropped and rotated back by pdftk. Acrobat validates it as correct PDF. I am wondering why the different treatment by pdf-, xe-, lua-latex...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "/Rotate 180" is valid PDF command.

Comment: Yes, but  xdvipdfmx reports `xdvipdfmx:warning: << /Rotate 180 >> found. (Not supported yet)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hope you don't mind that I've written that up in an answer: I didn't see your comment until I had!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an issue in `(x)dvipdfmx`: it does not support `/Rotate 180`. You won't see the warning with XeTeX unless you do the typesetting in two parts:

```
xelatex --no-pdf <test-file> && xdvipdfmx <test-file>.xdv
```

so perhaps it's easier to use `dvipdfmx` (with `\usepakage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`). In either case, running `(x)dvipdfmx` we get

```
warning: << /Rotate 180 >> found. (Not supported yet)
```

(`extractbb` also complains when using the `dvipdfmx` route: it is called during the `latex` run in that case.)

---

As [commented by Hironobu YAMASHITA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392007/possible-bug-with-graphicx/392012?noredirect=1#comment976042_392012)

> In TeX Live r44953-44964 (August 2017), xe(la)tex and (x)dvipdfmx started support of /Rotate in PDF. Thus, no problem will happen in TeX Live 2018

Comment: In TeX Live r44963--44964 (August 2017), xe(la)tex and (x)dvipdfmx started support of /Rotate in PDF. Thus, no problem will happen in TeX Live 2018.